# Biased binary search?

Tags: search-problem

Suppose I have some pre-existing knowledge of where within a sorted array the element I am looking for lies, in the form of a probability distribution $P(i)$ that tells me the probability of the goal element being found at position $i$.

When executing a binary search, the pivot has to be chosen at each step. I have a vague sense that I could, somehow, exploit my pre-existing knowledge of the element's location while retaining the $\Theta(\log N)$ asymptotic performance of binary search by using $P(i)$ to inform my choice of pivot at each step. If this is indeed a good idea, how should it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the binary search procedure to pick a weighted midpoint at each time step:

`1.  Input: Search key K, sorted array A, probability distribution P.`
`2.  Initialize m=0, M=n=len(A)=len(P).`
`3.  Repeat:`
`4.     Pick i with m <= i < M such that`
`5.       sum(P[j] for m<=j<i) <= sum(P[j] for m<=j<M)/2`
`6.     and`
`7.       sum(P[j] for i<j<M) <= sum(P[j] for m<=j<M)/2.`
`8.     Compare K with A[i].`
`9.     If K==A[i], return i.`
`10.    If K<A[i], set M=i.`
`11.    If K>A[i], set m=i+1.`
`12.    If m==M, return -1. (Fail.)`

Suppose the search key is in the array - i.e., `K==A[i]` for some `i`. The algorithm halves the value `sum(P[j] for m<=j<M)` after each iteration. Moreover, this sum starts at 1 and must always be at least `P[i]`. Thus the number of comparisons is at most `1+log_2(1/P[i])`.

If you want to retain the $O(\log n)$ worst case performance, you can mix a bit of the uniform distribution into your distribution. That is, run the algorithm with `P'=(P+U)/2`, where `U` is the uniform distribution. Then the number of iterations is at most `1 + log_2(1/P'[i]) <= 2 + min{ log_2(1/P[i]), log_2(n) }`.

Comment: An alternative (and probably simpler to implement) method of retaining $O(\log n)$ performance is to choose some constant $0 < c \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and letting your chosen index $i' = \text{clamp}(i, cn, (1-c)n)$.

Answer (score 0):

expand and reduce search:

start with the `bias` value (`guess`, `last`), expand the search range step-by-step to find the nearest `low` and `high` values (`low < actual < high`), then reduce the search range to find the `actual` value

here an implementation in javascript (sorry for not being theoretical) (even less theoretical: [a benchmark](http://jsbench.github.io/#24ecbbbc5d760eb771f776b227d8c36b))

```
function binarySearchBiased(haystack, needle, comparator, state) {
  // find nearest low and high values = expand search range
  let cmp = comparator(haystack[state.last], needle);
  if (cmp == 0) return state.last;
  function found(val) { state.last = val; return val }
  let low, high;
  const max_high = haystack.length - 1;
  if (cmp > 0) { // item > needle
    high = state.last;
    // find nearest low value
    for (let diff = 1; ; diff *= 2) {
      low = high - diff;
      if (low < 0) { low = 0; break }
      let cmp = comparator(haystack[low], needle);
      if (cmp == 0) return found(low);
      if (cmp < 0) break; // item < needle
      high = low - 1; // exclude low from range
    }
  }
  else { // item < needle
    low = state.last;
    // find nearest high value
    for (let diff = 1; ; diff *= 2) {
      high = low + diff;
      if (high > max_high) { high = max_high; break }
      let cmp = comparator(haystack[high], needle);
      if (cmp == 0) return found(high);
      if (cmp > 0) break; // item > needle
      low = high + 1; // exclude high from range
    }
  }

  // binary search = reduce search range
  while (low <= high) {
    const mid = low + ((high - low) >> 1);
    const cmp = comparator(haystack[mid], needle);
    if (cmp == 0) return found(mid);
    if (cmp < 0) { low = mid + 1 }
    else { high = mid - 1 }
  }
  return -1; // not found
}

function compare(item, needle) {
  return item - needle;
}

search_state = { last: 0 };
binarySearchBiased(haystack, needle, compare, search_state);
```

this is (obviously) optimized for 'sequential search' where last_needle and current_needle are very similar, aka 'neighbor search'